# How can I parse my String using regular expression to get only certain number of matches?

Tags: regular-expression

I am currently using this following regular expression to split my String into groups.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(\[([a-zA-Z0-9=]*)\]){0,1}@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$

Pty[R=4]@ID
```

I am getting four groups

```
1) Pty
2) [R=4]
3) R=4
4) ID
```

But, I need only three groups

```
1) Pty
2) R=4
3) ID
```

This regular expression should be also be able to accept Pty@ID to get two groups

```
1) Pty
2) ID
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: It might help if we knew what program you are using (`sed`?) and with what options. And maybe what *version* of the program.

Comment: Why do you care? Use `(?:...)` with perl/PCRE REs to avoid creating a capture group.

Comment: If it works in regex101.com, pcre php, that is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify any tools, so I use `perl` as example:

```
$ echo Pty[R=4]@ID | perl -nle '
    print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4"
        if /^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(\[([a-zA-Z0-9=]*)\]){0,1}@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/
'
Pty
[R=4]
R=4
ID

$ echo Pty@ID | perl -nle '
    print "$1\n$2\n$3\n$4"
        if /^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(\[([a-zA-Z0-9=]*)\]){0,1}@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/
'
Pty


ID
```

With regular expression capture group, you can use [backreferences](http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html) to get the previous matches. In `perl`, you can use `$1`, `$2`,...,`$n`.

In your case, you can use a [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to prevent `[R=4]` from being captured:

```
$ echo Pty[R=4]@ID |
perl -nle '
    print "$1\n$2\n$3"
        if /^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)(?:\[([a-zA-Z0-9=]*)\]){0,1}@([a-zA-Z0-9]*)$/
'
Pty
R=4
ID
```

As you mentioned `php` in your comment, you can use [php backreference](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.back-references.php) syntax `\1` or `\g1` or `\g{1}`.